# state_checkable does not work on view that extends checkable

Tags: android, state, statelistdrawable

I have a drawable state list selector that needs to display a different drawable when selected.

I extended the View class that uses the drawable with interface `Checkable` and this works ok.

However, when I only filter on `state_checkable`, it displays the image for the value of false. I assume this means that there is something wrong with my implementation.

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_6_default" android:state_checkable="false" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_disable_default" android:state_checkable="true" />
```

How do you get `state_checkable` and `state_checked` to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. You need to implement `onCreateDrawableState` and add the state_checked attr if the view is checked after calling super with an increased count of the number of extra attributes you have added. Don't have the code right here anymore, sorry.

Comment: Can you post your code? I've heard about this solution, but how should it looks like?

Comment: Sorry, can't find the code anymore. It should be fairly simple. Just add that state_checked to the states in `onCreateDrawableState` and increment the counter.

Answer (score 2):

Extending the previous answer for anyone else who may need the actual code for the onCreateDrawableState method. This is extracted from this library: https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/MultiChoiceAdapter

```
private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = {
  android.R.attr.state_checked
};

@Override
protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
  final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 2);
  if (isChecked) {
       mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
  }
  return drawableState;
}
```

Comment: I think you need `extraSpace + 1` instead of `2`. You are only adding 1 state attr.